# Modified Pumping Lemma

Tags: regular-languages

How could we prove the following modified Pumping Lemma:Let the language L has an infinite number of words, then there are words $x,y,z \epsilon \Sigma ^{*}$, so that $|xz|\leq |\Sigma_{k}|$, and each word $xy^{(i)}z, i\geq0 $ is in L.
Could you give me a hint how to begin?

Comment: Pumping lemma for what kind of language? What is $\Sigma_k$? What did you try?

Comment: $\Sigma_{k}$ is the set of the states. Let n be the length of a word of the language. Is there any relation between n and  $|\Sigma_{k}|$

Comment: OK. The pigeonhole principle gives you useful information about something that must have happened when an automaton with $q$ states reads $q$ or more characters.

Comment: Could you explain to me how to use this principle in this proof?

Answer (score 2):

If we compare your version to the "standard" [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) what do we see? that the only difference is that the standard lemma says

$$ |xy| \le p$$

while your lemma requires
$$ |xz| \le p$$
where $p$ is the pumping length. You call it $|\Sigma_k|$ but it's basically the same.

So, how do you prove the (standard) pumping lemma? The starting point is that 
if you process a string of length > $|\Sigma_k|$, then you must "hit" the same state twice. Then, $x$ is the prefix (the part of the string consumed until the first time you hit that state), $y$ is the middle part, consumed between the two times you hit that state, and $z$ is the leftovers, the part consumed after we hit that state twice.

Now to your question. Does it matter if $|xy|\le |\Sigma_k|$ or $|xz| \le |\Sigma_k|$?

**No.** In both cases we must hit a same state twice (this principle is called [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle): we visit more states than the total number of states, so one we must visit one state twice).

From here, you should be able to complete the proof yourself.